# Retrieve all entries from a ForeignKey and display them in the html template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I'm writing after checking different threads on similar issues with no luck whatsoever, hence I'm sharing with you my problem hoping you can give me a hint on how to solve it.

I am trying to build a keyword ranking checker and I have two models, Keyword and Ranking:

**models.py**

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    market = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)



class Ranking(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey(Keyword, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    position_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Basically, user will insert a list of keywords in the DB and an API will check each month the ranking for each keyword. The ranking model will store each ranking check and relate it to the keyword.

What I'd like to do is to display in the html template the list of keywords with their rankings (all of them because I want to show historical rankings too), and here is where I'm having issues. Basically I'm not able to retrieve all the rankings for a given keyword and pass it to the html as a template tag. I only can show the complete list of keywords and that's it.

**views.py**

```
def rankings(request):
    keywords = Keyword.objects.filter(market="es")
    return render(request, 'rankapi/marketview.html', {'keywords': keywords})
```

I've tried to do it the other way around, starting from rankings, but then I cannot display keywords which have no rankings.

**views.py**

```
def rankings(request):
    ranking = Ranking.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'rankapi/marketview.html', {ranking':ranking})
```

And then in the html:

**marketview.html**

```
    {% for rank in ranking %}
        {{rank.position}}{{rank.position_date}} {{rank.keyword.keyword}}
    {% endfor %}
```

But this is not showing keywords with no ranking associated to them (recently added keywords or still not checked ones).

Do you have any hint to help me solve this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution which I post here for reference if someone has similar issues:

```
  {% for keyword in keywords %}
       {{keyword.keyword}}
            {% for key in keyword.ranking_set.all %}
                {{key.position}}
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by

> Basically I'm not able to retrieve all the rankings for a given keyword and pass it to the html as a template tag. I only can show the complete list of keywords and that's it.

If there is a `ranking` object then its must that this `ranking` object  have an associated `keyword` object because in your `Ranking` model, you make a `ForeignKey` relationship with `keyword` and its a `required=True` field, django expecting its a required field implicitly i.e you can not create a `ranking` object without a 'keyword'.

So if you able to retrieve any 'ranking' object , then you should get associated keyword like,

```
{% for rank in ranking %}
        {{rank.position}}{{rank.position_date}} {{rank.keyword.keyword}}{{rank.keyword.domain}}
{% endfor %}
```

and so on..

Comment: Thank you! How would you show it in the HTML template so as to have {keyword} {position} {date}? I’ve tried a nested loop but seems not to work! Thanks